# merging two excel files into one

Tags: microsoft-excel, combine

I have two files with multiple worksheets in each that I would like to combine into one file. I want the formulas to remain but without the association to the old file.

Comment: Do you mean to do it by hand or to make a program to do it ?  if a program in which language .. I think your question is incomplete.

Comment: May not matter completely, but version of excel might help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the worksheet or worksheets you want to copy (use ctrl-click to select multiple tabs)
2. Right click one of the selected tabs
3. Select Move or Copy...
4. Select the destination workbook and the location within the workbook
5. Check "Create a copy" if you want to copy rather than move the worksheet(s)
6. Click OK.